# statusCode on error from looopback is not correct

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am making an API call to a commerce system (Hybris) using rest-connector in loopback. When there is an error, i am getting response statusCode as 200, whereas the error statusCode sent from hybris is 4xx. Also, when I hit the same URL from my browser (Chrome), I am getting statusCode 4xx. Why is loopback converting the statusCode to 200 and how do I get the original statusCode?

Comment: I imagine that you have a remote method that acts as a proxy for calling hybris .. can you provide a snippet of how your code so that we may help debug the problem? I've used 3rd party systems in the past and I've been able to pass the correct status code back transparently, so I'd like to view what's different.

Comment: +1 Can you provide a link to a test project on Github? See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/wiki/Issues#bug-report

Comment: It appears to be a bug - https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/loopbackjs/Wkj3Gz3wWJA/GA2bFfovBAAJ